# Javascript call back by function name in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to provide a call back function for an ajax call, where the function name is saved under the "data-apply" attribute of a form.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
        var apply = $form.attr('data-apply');
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),

            success: function(data, status) {
                var callBackFunc = new Function(apply);
                callBackFunc.call();
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

function addBubble(){
    alert('a');
}
```

The form:

```
<form id="111" class="form-horizontal " data-async data-target="#rating-modal" data-apply="addBubble();"  action="/some/action/performed" method="POST">
```

I want to avoid using `eval()` in this case, since `eval()` might introduce security and performance issues. Not sure `Function()` is a safer method or there is a completely different way to handle this.

So is there anyway to pass in a function callback in order to handle difference situations?

The original code was borrowed from: https://gist.github.com/havvg/3226804

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the function is globally defined, you can call it through the `window` object.

```
window["functionName"].call();
```

Remove the parentheses from addBubble

```
<form id="111" class="form-horizontal " data-async data-target="#rating-modal" data-apply="addBubble"  action="/some/action/performed" method="POST">
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));
        var apply = $form.attr('data-apply');
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),

            success: function(data, status) {
                if(typeof window[apply] == "function")
                    window[apply].call(); //window[apply](); or window[apply].apply(); will work too
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

function addBubble(){
    alert('a');
}
```

Comment: You can just do `window[apply]()`.  The `.call()` is used if you want to change the `this` value inside the function.

Comment: I know, I wanted to respect the way he was calling the callback function, that's all

Answer (score 5):

If the function is defined globally (i.e. on the `window` object) you could use `window[$form.attr('data-apply')]()` to call the callback.  Note that you would have to remove the `()` in `data-apply`